# Linux - Difference between mysql-server and php5-mysql packages

Tags: mysql, php-5.6

Hey everyone what is the difference between the linux packages:

mysql-server and php5-mysql?

Do I need both or just one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need no one if you are not a going to use development features and database.

If you are looking to start website development, install both along with Apache web server.